# No such file or directory (ls) in conjunction with tilde expansion

Tags: shell, tilde-expansion

I am writing a simple bash script and wanted to display all the items in a a particular directory. I tried doing the following:

```
desktop="~/Desktop/testr/"
echo $desktop
echo `ls $desktop`
```

However I keep getting the output:

```
~/Desktop/testr/
ls: ~/Desktop/testr/: No such file or directory
```

But when I run ls from the terminal, I can see the items. I suspect that the problem is that the `~` is not getting expanded but I thought that the double quotes would have taken care of that.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because within quoted strings there is no tilde expansion and tilde expansion comes before parameter substitution in the echo line.

The sequence of expansions is:

1. Tilde expansion
2. parameter expansion
3. command substitution
4. arithmetic expansion
5. Field splitting
6. Pathname expansion
7. Quote removal

See the [POSIX Shell Specification on Word Expansions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) for the gory details.

Comment: What would you recommend instead - using $HOME ?

Comment: I did not know that thanks! I was always under the impression that tilde expansion still happens with double quotes but not single quotes. Removing the quotes fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, using $HOME is what I do. Unless something is really screwed it should be set. But note that it only works for your own HOME--you can't replace `~username` with it.